# how to query a nested document in mongo

Tags: mongodb, mongovue

My document structure is as below

```
  "options" : {
    "fruit" : {
      "is" : false,
    }
    "vegetable" :{
     "is":true,
    }
  }
```

I want to pick up all basket items which are vegetable ONLY

I tried

```
{"options.vegetable.is":"true"} //not working
{"options":"vegetable"} // not working
```

I am using MongoVUE and trying with $eleMatch but still getting the syntax error..

Comment: Did you try `{"options.vegetable.is":true}`?  No double quotes around `true`

Comment: works ! without "". Thanks